# Oracle SQL. How to change table field datatype CLOB-->VARCHAR2

Tags: sql, oracle

I have database and some text fields are `CLOB` type, I need to change most of these into `VARCHAR2`.

Have tried to do that using SQL Developer tool, by clicking edit on table, but get error like this one:

The following SQL statement failed:

```
ALTER TABLE TBL_PEOPLE   MODIFY (PERSON VARCHAR2(150) )
```

Want to ask, how can this change be done

Answer (score 2):

You can't, directly. The code you tried will have got an `ORA-22859, presumably. (It's helpful to show the actual errors you get, of course).

You'll need to add a new `varchar2` column; copy the data across - or a substring of it if it might be larger than the new column you're creating; drop the `clob` column. You can rename the columns so it looks fairly transparent.

As in this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9fee3/1):

```
alter table tbl_people rename column person to clob_person;

alter table tbl_people add (person varchar2(150));

update tbl_people set person = clob_person;

alter table tbl_people drop column clob_person;
```

Obviously don't drop the old column until you're sure the data has copied without errors. Also take into account any constraints, indexes, etc. that might exist in the old column; they will need to be recreated. And anything that references the old column will have been invalidated - generally procedures will recompile themselves on next use.

So be careful, test it first, and plan some down time.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD (FIELD_LIST_TEMP VARCHAR2);  
UPDATE tablename SET FIELD_LIST_TEMP = FIELD_LIST;
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP COLUMN FIELD_LIST;
ALTER TABLE tablename RENAME COLUMN FIELD_LIST_TEMP TO FIELD_LIST;
```

Here FIELD_LIST existing column which is defined it as CLOB. With above query it will change from CLOB to VARCHAR2.